# Simulating mouse input programmatically in OS X

Tags: macos, input, mouse, touchscreen

Is it possible to simulate the actions of a mouse from a program in OS X? Specifically, the short version is that I'm trying to simulate a touchscreen using two webcams. So assuming I can get X,Y positions, can I send information to the OS as a mouse movement or click?

Edit- Or if it's particularly easy in another operating system I'd be willing to consider that.

Comment: Depending on your use case, there's an Instrument called "UI Recorder" that records whatever you do to the UI of your program and replays it when you want.

Comment: Thanks, but what I really want to do is send any arbitrary mouse input to the operating system.

Comment: I did this before by running a vnc server and writing a small vnc client to send mouse events to the server. There are open source vnc servers that do that, so a nice last resort would be to read the source of one.

Comment: Good idea Tom, I'll consider that.

Comment: You guys are life savers. I made a display wall by connecting a PowerMac to 6 projector displays arranged in a 2x3 grid comprising a single giant desktop. This works well, but with a bug: the OS won't let me programmatically resize a window taller than one row. I can resize it large with the mouse, but not with AppleScript. With this code, I can first use AppleScript to create and position a window, and then use a command-line clicky-drag program to stretch the window to the size I want. I note that there is no special drag event needed, just ordering the dispatch of these four events so as to

Answer (score 102, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You can use the [Quartz Event Services](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/Reference/QuartzEventServicesRef/Reference/reference.html) to simulate input events.

Assuming C, I wrote this quick example:

```c
#include <ApplicationServices/ApplicationServices.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
    // Move to 200x200
    CGEventRef move1 = CGEventCreateMouseEvent(
        NULL, kCGEventMouseMoved,
        CGPointMake(200, 200),
        kCGMouseButtonLeft // ignored
    );
    // Move to 250x250
    CGEventRef move2 = CGEventCreateMouseEvent(
        NULL, kCGEventMouseMoved,
        CGPointMake(250, 250),
        kCGMouseButtonLeft // ignored
    );
    // Left button down at 250x250
    CGEventRef click1_down = CGEventCreateMouseEvent(
        NULL, kCGEventLeftMouseDown,
        CGPointMake(250, 250),
        kCGMouseButtonLeft
    );
    // Left button up at 250x250
    CGEventRef click1_up = CGEventCreateMouseEvent(
        NULL, kCGEventLeftMouseUp,
        CGPointMake(250, 250),
        kCGMouseButtonLeft
    );
    // Now, execute these events with an interval to make them noticeable
    CGEventPost(kCGHIDEventTap, move1);
    sleep(1);
    CGEventPost(kCGHIDEventTap, move2);
    sleep(1);
    CGEventPost(kCGHIDEventTap, click1_down);
    CGEventPost(kCGHIDEventTap, click1_up);
    // Release the events
    CFRelease(click1_up);
    CFRelease(click1_down);
    CFRelease(move2);
    CFRelease(move1);
        return 0;
}
```

And assuming GCC, compile with:

```
gcc -o program program.c -Wall -framework ApplicationServices
```

Enjoy the magic.

Comment: @Rob: you're welcome. I hope the answer didn't come too late.

Comment: The answer was great but the documentation referenced now state that `These functions are still supported, but they are not recommended for new development`, they forgot to mention what would be recommended, anybody know?

Comment: According to the documentation, `these functions` refers strictly to the older set of event-related functions declared in the file `CGRemoteOperation.h` - which aren't used here.

Comment: CGEventCreateMouseEvent method does not seem to exist in recent OSX 10.10 and 10.11 SKD. Compiling from QT IDE I get the error: "no matching function for call to 'CGEventCreateMouseEvent'
    CGEventRef event = CGEventCreateMouseEvent(NULL, kCGEventMouseMoved, CGPointMake(x, y), 0 /*ignored*/);"

Comment: @YiannisMpourkelis: The method exists since OS X 10.4 ([see my output on 10.10.5](http://pastebin.com/tqRA8dV2)). If you use(d) Homebrew to install Qt, the problem [seems to be in the Qt5 formula](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/42014).

Answer (score 14):

`Swift` mouse move and click example:

```
func mouseMoveAndClick(onPoint point: CGPoint) { 
    guard let moveEvent = CGEvent(mouseEventSource: nil, mouseType: .mouseMoved, mouseCursorPosition: point, mouseButton: .left) else {
        return
    }
    guard let downEvent = CGEvent(mouseEventSource: nil, mouseType: .leftMouseDown, mouseCursorPosition: point, mouseButton: .left) else {
        return
    }
    guard let upEvent = CGEvent(mouseEventSource: nil, mouseType: .leftMouseUp, mouseCursorPosition: point, mouseButton: .left) else {
        return
    }
    moveEvent.post(tap: CGEventTapLocation.cghidEventTap)
    downEvent.post(tap: CGEventTapLocation.cghidEventTap)
    upEvent.post(tap: CGEventTapLocation.cghidEventTap)
}
```

Answer (score 11):

If you don't want to compile things and are looking for a shell-based tool, [Cliclick](http://www.bluem.net/en/mac/cliclick/) may be the solution.

Comment: Thank you for this recommendation, @ghoti. I have been searching for weeks for such a tool :)

Answer (score 4):

Here is a working C program based on jweyrick's answer:

```
// Compile instructions:
//
// gcc -o click click.c -Wall -framework ApplicationServices

#include <ApplicationServices/ApplicationServices.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int x = 0, y = 0, n = 1;
  float duration = 0.1;

  if (argc < 3) {
    printf("USAGE: click X Y [N] [DURATION]\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  x = atoi(argv[1]);
  y = atoi(argv[2]);

  if (argc >= 4) {
    n = atoi(argv[3]);
  }

  if (argc >= 5) {
    duration = atof(argv[4]);
  }

  CGEventRef click_down = CGEventCreateMouseEvent(
    NULL, kCGEventLeftMouseDown,
    CGPointMake(x, y),
    kCGMouseButtonLeft
  );

  CGEventRef click_up = CGEventCreateMouseEvent(
    NULL, kCGEventLeftMouseUp,
    CGPointMake(x, y),
    kCGMouseButtonLeft
  );

  // Now, execute these events with an interval to make them noticeable
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    CGEventPost(kCGHIDEventTap, click_down);
    sleep(duration);
    CGEventPost(kCGHIDEventTap, click_up);
    sleep(duration);
  }

  // Release the events
  CFRelease(click_down);
  CFRelease(click_up);

  return 0;
}
```

Hosted at https://gist.github.com/Dorian/5ae010cd70f02adf2107

Comment: I would use `usleep(duration*1000000)`. Otherwise you will only sleep for an integer number of seconds!

Comment: downvoted because it is without timeout and crashes my mac :)