# Simulate a mouse click with IOKit

Tags: c, macos, mouseevent, iokit

### Backstory:

I want to write a C program to automate clicks in a program running in OSx (in a desktop setting).

I first tried [Using Quartz Event Services to simulate input events](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3851793/311744). But then I had this problem: [Simulating mouse clicks on Mac OS X does not work for some applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2369806/simulating-mouse-clicks-on-mac-os-x-does-not-work-for-some-applications), and the answers didn't help in my case.

```
CGEventRef click1_down = CGEventCreateMouseEvent(NULL, kCGEventLeftMouseDown, CGPointMake(posx, posy), kCGMouseButtonLeft);
CGEventSetIntegerValueField(click1_down, kCGMouseEventClickState, 0);
// This down click works about 5% of the time.
CGEventPost(kCGHIDEventTap, click1_down);
usleep(30000);

CGEventRef click1_up = CGEventCreateMouseEvent(NULL, kCGEventLeftMouseUp, CGPointMake(posx, posy), kCGMouseButtonLeft);
CGEventSetIntegerValueField(click1_up, kCGMouseEventClickState, 1);
CGEventPost(kCGHIDEventTap, click1_up);

// I've tried every combination of CGEventSetIntegerValueField, usleep and CFRelease, nothing seems to help
// The only thing helping is repeating the line: "CGEventPost(kCGHIDEventTap, click1_down);" 100s of times, 
// then the down click works about 80% of the time, still not acceptable
```

I'm now turning to solution #3 suggested here: [How can Mac OS X games receive low-level keyboard input events?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7348886/how-can-mac-os-x-games-receive-low-level-keyboard-input-events)

(this might also help [How can I simulate the touch events by IOHIDEvent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17105027/how-can-i-simulate-the-touch-events-by-iohidevent))

I tried with Karabiner by sending a mouse click on key press:

```
<item>
  <name>Right Mousebutton</name>
  <identifier>rightMouseButton</identifier>
  <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::H, PointingButton::LEFT</autogen>
</item>
```

And this sends the click 100% of the time, but I want to send the click with by writing C code (to have greater control). Tough I'm not sure, Karabiner seems to use IOKit to send events, so I think this should work in my case, if I'm able to send mouse events with IOKit.

---

So my question is basically: how do I write a C program to simulate a mouse left click with IOKit ? [The documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeviceDrivers/Conceptual/IOKitFundamentals/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP0000018-BAJFFJAD) is very sparse and I didn't manage to do it.

I tried getting inspiration from some projects:

- https://github.com/tekezo/Karabiner
- https://github.com/NoobsArePeople2/manymouse

Comment: Did you ever manage to find some decent resources or documentation on this? I found [this](https://github.com/ccMSC/ckb/blob/master/src/ckb-daemon/input_mac.c) which I was able to adapt to suit my needs. It seems like even StackOverflow is lacking in I/O Kit experts!